# What does input parameter 'd' mean in D3.js function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to understand this code:

```
var w = 900;
var h = 200;
var barPadding = 1;

var dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
            11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("div")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
 .data(dataset)
 .enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (w / dataset.length);
 })
 .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - (d * 4);
 })
 .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
 .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d * 4;
 })
```

I can't figure out what does 'd' and 'i' mean as input parameters inside callback functions. Probably it's very simply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you give an array of elements for the `data()` function, d3 iterates it for you when you do the enter() call. In the callback what `d, i` means is an element from the `dataset` array and its index.

When you write:

```
   svg.selectAll("rect")
 .data(dataset)
 .enter()
 .append("rect")
```

D3 creates a bunch of `<bar>` elements, one for each entry in the array (for each entry the associated data along with index on the original array is given by `d, i`). More importantly, it also associates the data for each entry in the array with that DOM element, as a **data** property.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand

Answer (score 3):

`d` is the data value being rendered, `i` is the index of that data value in the data array.

Therefore, when rendering the first data point, `d` is 5 , and `i` is 0